# So... Redux action dispatch is sync or async? (Without thunk or saga)

Tags: reactjs, redux, flux

I am little confused about behaviour when I dispatch `redux` action.

**Example:**

```
onPressAdd() {
    this.props.addFloor({
        name: this.state.floor_name,
    });
    console.log(this.props.floors);
}
```

I am calling redux action `addFloor` what adds floor into array in store, then I console.log this variable and I expecting updated state (`[{name:'whatever'}]`) but I am getting `[]` (empty array)

**Example 2:**

```
async onPressAdd() {
    await this.props.addFloor({
        name: this.state.floor_name,
    });
    console.log(this.props.floors);
}
```

In this example I am getting perfectly fine updated store: `[{name:'whatever'}]`

I am reading everywhere that "Redux actions dispatch is sync if there is no thunk or saga (Direct way: dispatch action->reduce->store", but rhis is proof that dispatches are ASYNC.

So where is truth?

Comment: Async!  Coz it doesn't work without `thunk`.

Comment: I am not using thunks :D I am just doing state update in store :D

Comment: Actions are sync (that's why you need `thunk` and similars). The problem is that despite `actions` beeing `sync`. React's reactivity system is not. By the time you are calling `console.log` React's didn't finished the updates internally...

Answer (score 8):

Dispatching by itself is 100% synchronous.

This is a tiny implementation of a Redux store:

```js
function createStore(reducer) {
    var state;
    var listeners = []

    function getState() {
        return state
    }

    function subscribe(listener) {
        listeners.push(listener)
        return function unsubscribe() {
            var index = listeners.indexOf(listener)
            listeners.splice(index, 1)
        }
    }

    function dispatch(action) {
        state = reducer(state, action)
        listeners.forEach(listener => listener())
    }

    dispatch({})

    return { dispatch, subscribe, getState }
}
```

By the time `dispatch()` returns, the store has executed your reducer function, and called all the store subscriber callbacks.

It's only when you start adding middleware into the store that the dispatching process can be interrupted, because any middleware can delay, stop, or rewrite any action that was dispatched.

What you're seeing in that example is actually based on how React works.  Inside of that click handler, React has not yet re-rendered and updated the props of the component, so `this.props.whatever` will still be the same before and after the dispatch.

Comment: Ok, so `Example 2` is correct implementation when I need to do actions after store is updated.

Comment: Both examples appear correct. You don't have to `await` for the dispatch to complete - just do something else on the next line after `dispatch()`.

Answer (score 2):

The key thing is to realise that React doesn't update the props of your component until the execution of a called handler is not finished as a macrotask. Hence, your `console.log` after `dispatch` doesn't have updated props yet.

Roughly saying, doing your `Example 2`, you simply split it and get a new microtask with all included after `await` line, which will be executed after the props are updated.

That would be the same if you do `Promise.resolve(this.props.addFloor(...)).then(() => console.log(this.props.floors))` without `async/await`.